# ant build failed error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: java, utf-8, ant

Have an ant build script which builds some java files. These files may have existed in a windows environment previously, though I am attempting to build and compile them on OSX. The file in question seems to be encoded with the following

```
u'Western (Windows 1252)'
```

The error I receive is

```
error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
```

Does anyone have experience rectifying these types of issues?

Comment: Re-save the file with UTF-8 encoding and re-run the ANT target. Should fix your issue.

Comment: And already asked lots of times:, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995057/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8-error

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with a text editor that allows good control over coding, such as Emacs, and save the file in UTF-8.

Comment: There is a large number of files which might have this issue... say 200?

Comment: Emacs can be automated to do that. Surely other editors can too.