# I closed netbeans and now my project doesnt run, what to do?

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is the message that i get when trying to run the project:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Netbeans Projects\\CryptoFever2" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Netbeans Projects\CryptoFever2\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Netbeans Projects\CryptoFever2\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 19 source files to C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Netbeans Projects\CryptoFever2\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Eclipse projects\CryptoFever2\src\Interfaz\Login.java:193: error: unmappable character (0xF1) for encoding UTF-8
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCryptoFever,"Usuario o contrase?a incorrectas");
                                                                                    ^
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Eclipse projects\CryptoFever2\src\Interfaz\New_user.java:177: error: unmappable character (0xE1) for encoding UTF-8
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "El email introducido no es v?lido");
                                                                                         ^
2 errors
1 warning
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I closed netbeans and saw a message before, something like "there are processes open". Now cant run the project.

Thanks in advance,

Editted: I exported the project, then reinstalled JDK and netbeans and everything is ok,

Comment: Try `ant -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -f ....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having an encoding problem with your source file. It appears you have some accented characters in your message dialog which the compiler is not able to handle. I would check the encoding of your source files to make sure they are UTF-8 and make sure your compiler is set to use the same.

Also, see this post for similar responses: ["Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995057/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8-error)

Comment: i have fixed enconde problem now i get that message everytime i run the project:

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
Copying 10 files to C:\Users\Albertt\Desktop\Netbeans Projects\CryptoFever2\build\classes
compile:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 48 seconds)

hhow can i remove that?

Comment: That looks much better, at least you can build your program now. Are you concerned about the warning message? That is saying you have a mis-match between the JDK version that ant is using to build the project, versus the version that is expected. Do you have more than one version of the JDK installed? To fix it, make sure that you use the same JDK version everywhere (Netbeans, Ant, and any source/build files that might declare dependencies on JDK version). Also keep in mind that it's just a warning, and your project still is building correctly now.