# Unmappable character for encoding UTF8 in Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, encoding, utf-8

I am running jenkins on Tomcat Server which is running on Red Hat Linux. While I am trying to build a project in jenkins, I am getting following errors in jenkins

```
"unmappable character for encoding UTF8"
```

And the characters are `© �`

where as in IntelliJ, I can run the build without getting any error.

If I have to change the default encoding in Jenkins, then How to do that and what encoding I have to set over there to build the code.

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995057/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8-error

Comment: Is it something related to Jenkins?